# jquery: separate tag and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, each

I have:

```
// $(this): <span class="class1"><span class="class2"></span> Some text</span>
$(this).children().each(function () {
    console.log(this);
});
```

from the console I got only the span with class2, How I can get also the text? something like:

```
['<span class="class2"></span>', 'Some text']
```

Comment: to get the text you can use `$(this).text();` i really dont understand your question this is as much as i can suggest

Comment: atually that text is the innerHtml or Text of the node `this` so using the children u can not find.

Comment: You can try using `console.log($(this).html())` and/or `console.log($(this).text())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(this).children()` will only return child nodes that are elements.

You'll want to use [`$(this).contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get all the nodes, including text nodes. :)

You can then filter these nodes to just get elements and text (see [node types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)):

```
$(this).contents().filter(function() {
  return (this.nodeType === 1) || (this.nodeType === 3);
})
```

Comment: then with every node I got, I did this.outerHTML and this.textContent to get what I want, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

notice the diference between `.contents()` and `.children()`. You require the former

While .children() return all available elements, .contents also return text and comments

Comment: Good point made here that `.contents()` also returns comment nodes - watch out for these if you're just expecting uncommented text.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your output like this

```
jQuery(".class1").contents()
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.